# Why Balance is not deducted from source- signer in parity-bridges-common?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-parachain-template, parity-bridges-common

I was working on `parity-common-bridges` and was transferring balance from millau chain to rialto chain account using this script.

```
RUST_LOG=runtime=trace,bin-substrate=trace,bridge=trace \
./target/release/bin-substrate  send-message millau-to-rialto \
            --source-host localhost \
            --source-port $MILLAU_PORT \
            --source-signer //Alice \
            --target-signer //Bob \
            --lane 00000000 \
            --origin Target \
            transfer \
            --amount 100000000000000 \
            --recipient 5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty \
```

The problem here i am facing is that the balance is not deducted from source-signer, only the transaction fee is deducted from the same. On the other side balance is deducted from target-signer and is transferred to recipient account. My concern is that balance should be deducted from source-signer. If anyone can help me with this issue.